# Convergence in distribution $\implies$ almost sure convergence on countable probability space?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\left(\Omega, \mathcal A, P\right)$ be a *countable* probability space. Then it is true that convergence in probability implies almost sure convergence. Does convergence in distribution imply almost sure convergence? I'm guessing that it does not, but I haven't been able to produce a counter-example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Omega = \{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$, $P(\{\omega_1\}) = P(\{\omega_2\}) = 1/2$;
$$
\xi_n(\omega_i) = (-1)^{n+i}, i = 1,2, n\ge 1.
$$
Then $\xi_n$ converge to a symmetric Bernoulli random variable (they just share this law), but there is no almost sure convergence. (For both $\omega$ the values alternate.)

Comment: That's about as simple as it gets, thank you!